# Why is my swapfile not getting automatically mounted?

Tags: swap, fstab, btrfs

I always have to manually activate the swapfile after boot. What's wrong? Here is my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=65238893-d167-43fd-9c3d-489759c09f06 /               btrfs   defaults,subvol=@ 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=4e5c83d5-a781-4af7-a205-f137974d998e /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=68C0-029E  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=65238893-d167-43fd-9c3d-489759c09f06 /home           btrfs   defaults,subvol=@home 0       2
UUID=65238893-d167-43fd-9c3d-489759c09f06 /swap           btrfs   defaults,noatime,subvol=swap  0   0
/swap/swapfile  none    swap    sw  0   0
```

Here is the output of `sudo btrfs sub list /; ls /swap`:

```
ID 256 gen 59227 top level 5 path home
ID 318 gen 62429 top level 5 path @
ID 319 gen 62429 top level 5 path @home
ID 330 gen 62180 top level 318 path swap
swapfile
```

Comment: Is `/swap` mounted? Does `/swap/swapfile` exist? What happens when you run `sudo swapon -a`?

Comment: I'm seeing three mount points with the very same `UUID` ... 

Comment: `sudo swapon -a` works, it just doesn't get activated on boot. The three mount points with the same UUID are different BTRFS volumes.

Comment: Please add output of `sudo btrfs sub list /; ls /swap` command

Comment: Your swapfile is not automatically mounted, because a swapfile cannot and never is mounted. Include the output of `swapon` in your question, before and after you executed `sudo swapon -a`. Check whether the issue is not with your btrfs mounts.

Comment: @vanadium It's OK for `btrfs`. But I suspect that something is wrong, e.g. subvolume name is `@swap`, not `swap`, etc.

Comment: The swap subvolume does get mounted though. And it's called `swap`, not `@swap` (confirmed). `swapon` has no output before I execute `sudo swapon-a`, afterwards it's ```NAME           TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swap/swapfile file   8G   0B   -2```

Comment: Please don't add information to comments. [edit] your question. The problem may be with the same name of a subvolume and the directory Rename the subvolume to `@swap`

Comment: @Pilot6 I edited the question. I will also try to rename the subvolume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because you have the same name `swap` for your subvolume and the directory you mount to.

I didn't test it, but `mount` could throw an error on

```
UID=65238893-d167-43fd-9c3d-489759c09f06 /swap           btrfs   defaults,noatime,subvol=swap  0   0
```

Then the next line wasn't used as well.

Your `swapfile` was created not on a separate subvolume, but on `@`.

Comment: Thanks, it does work now, although I had to create @swap a child of the root subvolume rather than @, so maybe that was a problem too.